# OS X / Synology NAS stuck share (home / home-1)

Tags: macos, share, reboot, nas

I am using Mac OS X 10.11.6 and VirtualBox 5.1.12, with a share ("home") on my Synology NAS.

I have had this issue for a long time but have never got round to finding a proper solution.

I use home folders from the NAS share, when looking at the location of virtual disks in VirtualBox, the path is:
/Volumes/home/app content/VirtualBox/Virtual Disks

Everything works fine, until the Synology NAS does an update and reboots. I then find myself in the position where I no longer have a 'home' share, but a 'home-1' share, this then means VirtualBox cannot find the virtual disks because it is looking in 'home' and not 'home-1'.

This has just happened meaning I have no access to Virtual Disks, if I run the following command

```
mount ; ls -na /Volumes/home* ; id
```

I get the following results

```
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
total 0
drwx------+ 2 501  80   68  8 May 07:05 .
drwxrwxrwt@ 5 0    80  170  8 May 07:25 ..
uid=501(jamesgriffin) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),703(com.apple.sharepoint.group.3),100(_lpoperator),704(com.apple.sharepoint.group.4),702(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2)
```

Now, if i go to the finder, click on my 'home' share (from the favourites sidebar), and run the above command again, I get the following results.

```
mount ; ls -na /Volumes/home* ; id
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
//James%20Griffin@DiskStation.local/home on /Volumes/home-1 (afpfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by jamesgriffin)
/Volumes/home:
total 0
drwx------+ 2 501  80   68  8 May 07:05 .
drwxrwxrwt@ 6 0    80  204  8 May 07:40 ..

/Volumes/home-1:
total 160
drwxrwxrwx  1 501  20   2710  2 Apr 19:23 #recycle
drwx--x--x  1 501  20    264 12 Feb 11:37 - sort
drwx------@ 1 501  20    636  8 May 07:40 .
drwxrwxrwt@ 6 0    80    204  8 May 07:40 ..
-rwx--x--x@ 1 501  20  38916  8 May 07:40 .DS_Store
drwx--x--x@ 1 501  20    264 10 Jul  2016 .TemporaryItems
-rwx--x--x  1 501  20  20992 18 Apr 20:03 ShowCrosshairs.dll
-rwx--x--x@ 1 501  20  11776 18 Mar 14:52 Thumbs.db
drwx--x--x  1 501  20   1928 26 Feb 13:37 app content
-rwx--x--x  1 501  20    376  3 Jan 18:16 b404b44adb23d84f076ac3193777d7e7d41c39af.Tls
drwx--x--x  1 501  20    264 13 Nov 16:14 collections
drwx--x--x  1 501  20   5804  7 May 12:59 downloads
drwx--x--x  1 501  20    806 12 Feb 11:43 folder stucture testing
drwx--x--x  1 501  20    534 23 Jan 21:16 mac finder shortcuts
drwx--x--x  1 501  20    840 13 Mar 19:33 my work
drwx--x--x  1 501  20    264  8 May 03:26 photo
drwx--x--x  1 501  20    568 16 Dec 14:30 repository
drwx--x--x  1 501  20    704 25 Sep  2016 sorted
drwx--x--x@ 1 501  20    806 24 Dec 10:50 sorting
drwx--x--x@ 1 501  20   2098 20 Apr 01:46 temp
uid=501(jamesgriffin) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),703(com.apple.sharepoint.group.3),100(_lpoperator),704(com.apple.sharepoint.group.4),702(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2)
```

I think I understand what is happening (NAS reboots, OS X does not release share, NAS Starts, OS X gives share new name of 'home-1' as it see's 'home' as taken). However, this is quite inconvenient, as I have my virtual machine open, do some work, go to bed, NAS automatically updates, I wake up to find my virtual machine is no longer available!

My knowledge of the terminal is very limited so I don't like to mess about with it when I'm not too sure what I'm doing. A reboot resolves the issue, but in the process I loose any unsaved work that was done in the Virtual Machine. (I do save regularly to avoid any issues, but it's a hassle having to restart the machine, and open everything back up to get where I was, and it just seems wrong that I have to do that)

I suppose my question is, is this normal? and is there any way to forcibly unmount 'home' so I don't get a 'home-1' share any more?

I did try the command

```
umount /volumes/home
```

with result

```
umount: /volumes/home: not currently mounted
```

As I say, I don't like messing in the terminal much (unless being guided) as I don't really know what I'm doing.

Ultimately, I always want my NAS share to be 'home' and never 'home-1' if possible, is there any way to do this, or any advice if I am doing something fundamentally wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for anyone else that may run into this problem, I found a way around fixing it, without the need to reboot the machine.

1. Open Finder
2. Select Go > Go To Folder...
3. Type '/volumes'

Here, I had a folder (mount point) called 'home'. Delete it.

Remount 'home' share and now I have 'home' instead of 'home-1'